# AWS code pipeline not getting environment variables

Tags: docker, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm deploying my Django app using AWS code pipeline which is dockerized and I was storing my env variables inside an env file for local development but for the code pipeline I set them all inside environment variables but the variables are still getting `None`.

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    depends_on:
      - db

  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/static

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  static-data:
```

getting env variable in django like:

```py
os.environ.get('FRONTEND_URL')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case, I put all env variables inside my AWS CodeBuild environment variables and call them in my docker environment as below.

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
       - VARIABLE_NAME: ${VARIABLE_NAME}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the env file in the docker compose itself along with relative path.

```
....
....
app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    env_file:
    - <web-variables1.env>
    volumes:
      - static-data:/vol/web
    depends_on:
      - db
....
....
```

[Refer more details at documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: I don't want to put my env file inside my repo because it has some secret keys

Comment: If the keys are kept in  .bash_profile in linux or env variable in windows, the terminal window or IDE needs to be restarted to get the updated one.